# Horizontal ::before and ::after for absolute ul

Tags: html, css

Trying to figure out ::before and ::after elements
I've got a drop down navigation in a form of absolute ul. It's got a fixed width, and i need a filled background around it for navigation to be full screen, yet the subnav being right under parent li.
Yet, the background appears at the top and the bottom. Not on the sides of it.

Here is html

```
<li class="parentli">
  <a href="whatevs">Link</a>
  <ul class="subnav">
    <li class="blankli><div class="supnavimg"></div></li>
    <li class="navitem"></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and the css

```
ul.subnav {position:absolute;top:15px;}
ul.subnav::before {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0 100%;
  content: " ";
}
ul.subnav::after {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 0 100%;
  content: " ";
 }
.blankli {position:relative;}
.supnavimg {
  position:absolute;
  width:40%;
  right:-100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REVISED:**   The following positions the item using width, height, and margins.   There may be cleaner ways to do this, but this should get you started.

```
ul.subnav 
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 800;
    width: 320px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px; /* position entire element vertically */
    margin-left: 60px; /* position entire element horizontally */
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 88, 72, .9);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
}

ul.subnav::before 
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: -40px; /* (padding * -1) of main element */
    content: "";
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
}

ul.subnav::after 
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px; /* position ::after item vertically */
    margin-left: 320px; /* position ::after item horizontally */
    content: " ";
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: it moved ul slightly to the right and before/after bgs stayed at the same place

Comment: You are correct.   You may have to use positioning to move the before and after elements.

Comment: I floated them left and right, and I've tried absolute position with left and right 0. They've disappeared at all in both cases

Comment: I updated the example above.  See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/eat_sleep_code/q1n3gzd9/

Comment: the problem is ul.subnav can not be relative. it's drop down that requires absolute positioning to be displayer properly...

Comment: @wharry it should work if you set it to absolute too.